# MongoDB: To Find Objects with Three Integer Values, Sort Range of Three Values or Perform Three Queries?

Tags: mongodb

My basic question is this: **Which is more efficient?**

```
mongo_db[collection].find(year: 2000)
mongo_db[collection].find(year: 2001)
mongo_db[collection].find(year: 2002)
```

**or**

```
mongo_db[collection].find(year: { $gte: 2000, $lte: 2002 }).sort({ year: 1 })
```

More detail: I have a MongoDB query in which I'll be selecting objects with 'year' attribute values of either 2000, 2001, or 2002, but no others.  Is this best done as a `find()` with a `sort()`, or three separate `find()`s for each value?  If it depends on the size of my collection, at what size does the more efficient search pattern change?

Comment: What are your indexes? Unlikely to change the answer but probably the most important performance-related issue here.

Answer (score 0):

The single query is going to be faster because Mongo only has to scan the collection (or its index) once instead of three times.  But you don't need a `sort` clause for your range query unless you actually want the results sorted for a separate reason.

You could also use `$in` for this:

```
mongo_db[collection].find({year: {$in: [2000, 2001, 2002]}})
```

Its performance should be very similar to your range query.

Comment: I **do** want the sort. Does that maintain that the `$in` clause is faster than the separate hits?

Comment: @PatZabawa Even with the sort I would expect so, yes.  But for concrete answers to performance questions, you need to actually test it out using your own data and hardware.